# Return variable from NodeJS ExpressJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

Wazzup coders,

I'm using Express and Ajax to send data from the client to NodeJS. I cannot understand why my variable isn't defined outside of the function. Can anyone show me where I may be going wrong?

```
//send javascript to client
    res.send(`
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var size = {
          clientwidth: window.innerWidth,
          clientheight: window.innerHeight
        };
        var objectData = JSON.stringify(size);
        $.post('/size', { clientwh: objectData });
    </script>
    `);

//retrieve javascript from client
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.post('/size', (req, res) =>
    {
        var clientwidth = req.body.clientwh.match(/\d+/);
        var clientheight = req.body.clientwh.match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/gm);
        const clientResolution = [clientwidth, clientheight];
        res.json({ok: true});
        console.log(clientResolution)
    });
    
    console.log(clientResolution) //ReferenceError: clientResolution is not defined
```

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

**Variable Scope**

First, `clientResolution` is defined as a local variable inside of the `app.post()` callback function so it is scoped to that function and ONLY available inside that callback function.

See the comments I inserted into your code:

```
app.post('/size', (req, res) =>
{
    var clientwidth = req.body.clientwh.match(/\d+/);
    var clientheight = req.body.clientwh.match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/gm);
    const clientResolution = [clientwidth, clientheight];
    res.json({ok: true});
    console.log(clientResolution)

    // clientResolution is only available inside this function block 
    // where it was declared
});

// clientResolution is NOT available out here because this 
// is outside of its declaration scope
```

If you're confused by this concept of "scope" for Javascript variables, then that's something you really need to learn in order to program in Javascript.  Here's a [tutorial](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-scope/) that covers many types of scope (block, function, module, global).

**Client State on a Server**

Second, even if you defined the variable in a higher scope so its value would be available outside the function, that is the wrong way to design server-side code.  The server responds to the needs of many different clients and thus you cannot store state that belongs to one specific client in a module-level or global-level variable because different clients will tromp on each other's data.

In general, you want to design your server to be as stateless as possible because that makes it easier to write and scale.  But, if you find you must store some state, then you would typically use a "session" which will be an object stored on the server, uniquely for each client that is connected to a particular client by a cookie.  Then, when you put state data in the session object, it will be unique for that particular client.  You can use the `express-session` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) to get started with session objects.